# How do you delete certain messages from a specific username not ID

Tags: discord, discord.js

```js
twitchClient.on('timeout', async (channel, username, user, reason, duration) => {

    discordClient.on('message', async (message, messages) => {
        async function deleteMessage() {
            await discordClient.channels.cache.get("901568598538063932")
            .messages.fetch({limit: null})
            .then(message.delete(messages.first(user["display-name"]).author.name))
        }
        await deleteMessage()
    })
        
    async function sendMessage() {
        const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "API url");
        
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

        const users = { 
        username: "User Timed Out",
        avatar_url: 'https://i.imgur.com/GUrbNsB.jpg',
        content: `**${username} has been timed out for ${duration} seconds.**`
        }
        request.send(JSON.stringify(users));
    }

    await sendMessage()
});
```

I have this code for twitch chat to sync in discord and I want to do on event timeout on twitch
I want it to delete the messages of a certain name on the channel is it possible without ID
I am lost on how to do it like I can delete the last message but not from a specific user and I
only have one webhook so the id of all usernames will be the same

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: This code is for Discord.js v13.3.0*

---

As stated by the error, you're trying to access an undefined variable called `messages`. This is because you did not define it in the `then()` arguments, you instantly went to a callback.

`then()` is a function that allows for you to provide parameters to add. You can simply put the collection of messages as one variable called `messages` and pass it to the callback accordingly.

```js
// DON'T do this
messages.fetch({limit: null})
            .then(message.delete(messages.first(user["display-name"]).author.name))

// DO this
messages.fetch({limit: null})
            .then((messages) => message.delete(messages.first(user["display-name"]).author.name))
```